# Sum of series in c language

Tags: c

Sum of series using c language

*sample* input : 12 15
*sample* output : 54

*sample* input : 1 100
*sample* output : 5050

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    
    int a, b;
    
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    printf("%lld",a*(b+1)/2);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);` ==> `if (scanf("%d%d", &a, &b) != 2) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);`

Comment: `printf("%lld",a*(b+1)/2);` ==> `printf("%d\n",a*(b+1)/2);` or `printf("%lld",(long long)a*(b+1)/2);`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them, like for example actually *asking* a question.

Comment: What's the question? What's the equation, or is this some Mensa test I'm supposed to take?

Answer (score 2):

Your formula: `a*(b+1)/2` is wrong

For `a + (a+1) + (a+2) + ... + (b-1) + b` use the formula:

```
((b+1)*b - a*(a-1))/2  or (b-a+1)(b+a)/2
```

(assuming that `b >= a`)

So the program could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a, b;
    
    if (scanf("%d %d", &a, &b) != 2) exit(1);
    if (b < a) exit(1);
    printf("%d", ((b+1)*b - a*(a-1))/2);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `%lld` format specifier is used to print a `long long int`.  The argument you're passing has type `int`.  Mismatching format specifiers triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which in this case will likely result in output you don't expect.

To print an `int` use `%d`.

```
printf("%d",a*(b+1)/2);
```